# Radio button in each row of table, then sending to servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, jstl

Basically what I'm looking to do is the following:

Have an HTML table in my jsp. Each row corresponds to a specific part. In one of the columns I would like to have a radio button that corresponds to an action for that specific part Let's say 'Delete', 'Archive', 'Ignore'. I'd like to pass this information on to my servlet.

Ideally I'd like to parse the entire table, for each part ID seeing whether the user selected 'Delete', 'Archive' or 'Ignore' then perform an action based on that. I have two questions:

First, What is the best way/is it possible to access the entire table from the request?

Second, How can I access the radio buttons for a specific row (part id) and determine which one was selected?

Comment: Just give all input elements a name and a value the usual way? Browser will send entered/selected values as request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Row ID</th>
        <th>Radio</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12341</td>
        <td>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12341_radio" value="1">Delete</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12341_radio" value="2">Archive</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12341_radio" value="3">Ignore</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12342</td>
        <td>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12342_radio" value="1">Delete</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12342_radio" value="2">Archive</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12342_radio" value="3">Ignore</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12343</td>
        <td>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12343_radio" value="1">Delete</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12343_radio" value="2">Archive</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12343_radio" value="3">Ignore</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12344</td>
        <td>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12344_radio" value="1">Delete</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12344_radio" value="2">Archive</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12344_radio" value="3">Ignore</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12345_radio" value="1">Delete</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12345_radio" value="2">Archive</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="12345_radio" value="3">Ignore</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="id_list" val="12341,12342,12343,12344,12345">
</form>
```

In above code i have put common name for radio in same row. And every group name contains rowid following with `_radio` and an hidden input containing comma separated list of row ids.

On submitting form on servlet side you should perform operations listed below :-

1. First of all get the hidden input.
2. Separate then into an array.
3. Iterate over array so you have id list and form string `rowid_radio` i.e. '12341_radio','12342_radio' etc.
4. then you can get values of all the radio buttons from different row.